# Java, Maven, connect SQL , no suitable driver

Tags: java, sql, maven, derby

I am building a project using Netbeans IED, with java. The project is using maven and I am attempting to connect it to sql database which I am having issue's. The code works in java but not with maven.

Here the error: 
No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Database

Java Code:

```
public class DatabaseTest {

    public static Connection ConnectionObj = null;
    public static Statement SqlStatement = null;
    public static ResultSet Sqlresult = null;
    public static ResultSetMetaData MetaData = null;
    public static String query = "Select * from Wallet";
    public static String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Database";
    public static String user = "ABM";
    public static String pass = "password2";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {    
            //Allows you to connect the database
            ConnectionObj = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            SqlStatement = ConnectionObj.createStatement();
            Sqlresult = SqlStatement.executeQuery(query);
            MetaData = Sqlresult.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Connection worked");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Prom depency's:

```
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
 <groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.47</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
  <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
  <version>10.14.1.0</version>

</dependency>
```

https://gyazo.com/8937aada3bd4a8f5b108b5dc9b386dd7

Comment: Do you know what the IDE thinks your class path is?

Comment: the class path is jdk1.8.0..16

Comment: You should see a standard output in the built-in terminal of Netbeans when you run your program. Can you paste it here?

Answer (score 1):

This part of your POM file is incorrect:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.47</version>
  </dependency>
```

Your program is attempting to use JDBC to connect to a Derby database, so you should be using a Derby JDBC driver, not a MySQL JDBC driver.

Replace the above with the following:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.14.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

(Use the same version as your main Derby version ...)

---

> The code works in Java but not with Maven.

Curious.  Perhaps you are setting the runtime classpath correctly in the Java case.